Python - Flask blueprint parameter?
I need to pass a parameter (some_url) from the main app to the blueprint using Flask
This is my (oversimplified) app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_bp, url_prefix='/mybp', some_url ="http....")

This is my (oversimplified) blueprint
my_bp = Blueprint('mybp', __name__, url_prefix='/mybp')

@repositories_bp.route('/entrypoint', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def entrypoint():
    some_url = ????

Not sure this is the way to go, but I parsed countless threads,  I just cannot find any Info about this
Thanks for your help

you can use g object for the current request which stores temporary data,
or you can use session to maintain data between multiple requests which usually stores this data in the client browser as a cookie,
or you can store the data in the app.config to maintain a constant value.

Thanks for answering!
Note the other answer to this question includes code the person asking the question might try.

This seems to work
In the main app
app.config['some_url'] = "http:..."

In the entry point
def entrypoint():
    some_url = current_app.config['some_url']

